# No puedo resolver este problema c#

Tags: c#

Hola alguien me puede decir como resolver esto?

Defina una clase Persona con 3 campos: Nombre, Edad y DNI. Escriba un algoritmo que
permita al usuario ingresar en una consola una serie de datos de la forma
"NombreDocumentoEdad". Una vez finalizada la entrada de
datos, el programa debe imprimir en la consola un listado el listado con la forma:
Nro.) Nombre (Edad)  DNI.

Ejemplo:

1. Juan Perez (40) 2098745
2. José García (41) 1965412

a) Utilizando un arreglo de Personas. Antes de comenzar con la carga el usuario debe
ingresar por consola la cantidad de personas que va cargar.

b) Utilizando un arraylist. En este caso el usuario no debe ingresar la cantidad de
personas que va a cargar, simplemente el proceso de entrada finaliza con un string
vacío.

Esto es lo que hago yo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace borrador
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de personas que se van a ingresar:");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string [] personas = new string[x];
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese sus datos con el siguiente formato (Nombre Edad DNI): ");
            string datos = Console.ReadLine();
            int contador = 0;
            while (contador <x)
            {
                personas[contador] = datos;
                Console.WriteLine("siguiente Nombre Edad DNI:");
                datos = Console.ReadLine();
                contador += 1;
            }

            Persona programa = new Persona(personas);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Persona
    {
        public string nombre, edad, dni;
        public Persona(string[] datos)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.Length; i++)
            {
                string s=datos[i].Split(" ");
                this.nombre=datos(0);
                this.edad=datos(1);
                this.dni=datos(2);
                Console.WriteLine(nombre,edad,dni);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: mi pregunta es, que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta para conseguir lo que me pide el enunciado...

Comment: En primer lugar estas pasando un array a la clase Persona que esta esperando un string.  Necesitas un loop que recorra el array personas e instancie una persona por cada iteracion

Comment: si, eso me di cuenta y lo cambie, pero sigo igual.

Comment: Pon la nueva version de tu codigo con el loop.

Comment: ahi ya lo puse..

Comment: El loop tiene que ir afuera en tu clase Program.  Vas a crear una persona por cada iteracion.  De la manera que lo hiciste estas creando una sola persona y reescribiendo las propiedades por cada iteracion.

Comment: Ya lo lograste o aun sigues teniendo problemas??

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría esto, depende de si estás obligado a usar arrays, usaría List<> ya que es más versatil,

en el caso de array

```
int cantidad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<Persona> listaPersonas = new List<Persona>()

for(int i = 0; i<cantidad; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Ingresar: Nombre Edad DNI:");
  var persona = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ").ToArray(); 
  //obtenés un array string[]

  //si sabés que siempre tienen 3 atributos las personas
  Persona p = new Persona();
  p.Edad = persona[0];
  p.Nombre = persona[1];
  P.Dni = persona[2];

  listaPersonas.Add(p);
}


public class Persona
{
   public int Edad {get;set;}
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public string Dni {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, tu codigo esta lleno de errores.. empiezo

como estas haciendo split por espacios " ", el texto de entrada 
"**Juan Perez (40) 2098745**" nunca va a funcionar

lo que tienes que hacer es hacer dos splits.

primero

```
 string s1=datos[i].Split("(");
```

haciendo esto s1[0] tendra el nombre , y s1[1] tendra la edad y el DNI
asi que debemos dividir s1[1] para extraer la edad y el DNI

```
 string s2=s1[1].Split(")");
```

Con esto :
s1[0] = Nombre
s2[0] = Edad
s2[1] = DNI

Probablemente necesites un trim para eliminar los espacios en blanco sobrantes.

siguiente error :

```
 *string datos = Console.ReadLine();*
 int contador = 0;
 while (contador <x)
 {
       personas[contador] = datos;
       Console.WriteLine("siguiente Nombre Edad DNI:");
       **datos = Console.ReadLine();**
       contador += 1;
}
```

por que estas leyendo los datos dos veces ?,
tienes que aprender a usar ciclos correctamente, esto esta provocando que el programa pida una linea de entrada adicional, pero esos datos jamas son ingresados al array de personas

```
 int contador = 0;
 while (contador <x)
 {
       datos = Console.ReadLine();
       personas[contador] = datos;
       contador++;
       if(contador <x)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("siguiente Nombre Edad DNI:");
       }
 }
```

ahora, el problema final: 
solo estas creando un objeto persona, lo que tienes que hacer es crear al inicio de tu void main un array de personas tambien :

```
 Persona[] PERSONAS = new Persona[x];
```

y en cada parte del ciclo crear una instancia de cada objeto :

```
 int contador = 0;
 while (contador <x)
 {
       datos = Console.ReadLine();
       personas[contador] = datos; //y podemos eliminar esto
       PERSONAS[contador] = new Persona(datos); 
       contador++;
       if(contador <x)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("siguiente Nombre Edad DNI:");
       }
 }
```

Full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace borrador
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de personas que se van a ingresar:");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string [] personas = new string[x];
            Persona [] PERSONAS = new Persona[x];
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese sus datos con el siguiente formato (Nombre Edad DNI): ");
            string datos = Console.ReadLine();
            int contador = 0;
            while (contador <x)
            {

                datos = Console.ReadLine();
                personas[contador] = datos;
                contador++;
                if(contador <x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("siguiente Nombre Edad DNI:");
                }
            }
            for(int c=0;c<x;c++)
            {
                PERSONA[c] = new Persona(personas[c]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Persona
    {
        public string nombre, edad, dni;
        public Persona(string datos)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.Length; i++)
            {
                string s1=datos.Split("(");
                string s2=s1[1].Split(")");
                nombre=s1[0];
                edad=s2[0];
                dni=s2[1];
                Console.WriteLine(nombre,edad,dni);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Naturalmente, recien empiezo y justamente por eso tengo estos problemas. Gracias!